# What is purpose of the 'properties' folder inside Sitecore Zip package?

Tags: packages, package-designer

We are using `Sitecore 9.3` on the project. My zip package takes a lot of space. When I opened my package `my-package-1.0.0.zip\package.zip\` with `7-Zip` I noticed that the *properties* folder takes a lot of space and it contains items that are already contained in the *items* folder.

Does someone know the purpose of the *properties* folder? Is it safe to remove it from the zip package? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not remove the properties folder, keep it as it is.

The file format of files under \package\items\ and \package\properties\items\ are different and they are storing different information:

1. File under Items folder storing the information about the item, its name, sort order etc., also it contains such data about fields like id, key, type, and content.
2. File under Properties folder storing the information about the database, version, language revision etc., also it contains information about fields like Shared/Versioned.